# Changing tokenisation behaviour

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm using Stanford Tokenizer for my project and I'm unable to understand and fix tokenization of a specific pattern.

Based on my configuration, if I tokenize string:

`"Hello World>"`

I will correctly get:

```
hello
world
>
```

But for string:
`"<Hello World>"`
I'm getting:

```
<hello world>
```

And I expect to receive:

```
<
hello
world
>
```

Any idea if I could configure the tokenizer in a way to not consider this specific pattern as a single token?

These are my current options set for the tonezer:
`-lowerCase -options "untokenizable=allKeep,americanize=true,normalizeOtherBrackets=false,normalizeParentheses=false"`

Help is much appreciated.